# Should webdev be a synonym of webdav

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[webdev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdev) has been made into a synonym for [webdav](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdav). This is a mistake (No offence, Bart.) Webdev is surely short for "Web Development" - however I can't prove this because it's now impossible to find the item that's tagged with it. (suggestions?)

Anyway - [webdev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdev) probably isn't a great tag for trex. Sure - it's all about web-development, but questions that really are about that are probably off-topic.

Wouldn't a simple deletion or re-tag have been a better solution?

Answer (score 6):

I think that this has probably been done with the best intentions; I've seen a number of misspellings of "WebDAV" as "WebDEV" (such as [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/webdev-url-getting-changed-into-tcmid-automatically-in-visio-workflow-designer) pre-edit) but I'd argue that the proper course of action there is to correct the error, not create a synonym between a correct tag and an incorrect one. Synonyms are a mechanism for creating a canonical version of multiple tags that mean the same thing, not a corrective measure.

The best thing to do would probably be to remove the synonym and then either correct or remove the [webdev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdev) tag when it's used (either retagging if it's a misspelling or removing if it's used correctly but is overly broad and/or redundant).

Comment: I would argue that synonyms as implemented on SE are for both creating a canonical version of multiple tags that mean the same thing AND as a corrective measure (if you look on stack overflow you'll find a number of synonyms that are correcting common errors.) However in this case I agree with you the use of a synonym is wrong as WebDEV has a different potential meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 17 questions tagged with [webdav](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdav) (see: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdav) and all of them appear to be WebDAV related, so the tag [webdev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdev) was obviously a typo.

I welcome the discussion to debate if [webdev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdev) should remain a synonym of [webdav](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webdav) (so the typo cannot be repeated and is automatically fixed/retagged) or if it should rather be deleted (in which case the typo can be made again, which brings more cleanup/retag work for this community).

If we would need a tag for Web Development, then I would suggest [web-dev](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-dev) since it is composed of two words, but indeed that would seem rather off topic for this site.

Comment: I'd say we should delete it.

Comment: Thing is, we can't delete a tag ourselves. Only option we have is to retag the question with the correct tag and make sure the incorrect spelled tag is not used in any question, then after 24 hours the tag should be deleted by the system. , see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags.

Answer (score 2):

I would say instead of making it synonym, we should delete it as `webdev`is surely been carrying wrong information here. Also, there is no scope of of a tag for Web Development as well because it is implicit whatever we are going to develop using Tridion will be a Web based development. Any more complexity related to web development should be asked out of this community - may be on Stackoverflow.

My take: We should delete this tag.